# How to merge two streams (without nulls) and apply conditions on pairs?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-streams

Consider I have two streams of data, is there a way to merge them and apply conditions on data between these two streams? For example

```
Stream A : A, B, C, D....
Stream B : -, A, -, -....
Composed : (A,-),(B,A),(C,-),(D,-)....
```

How to get composed stream above using rxjs? I would like to apply conditions on composed streams to raise some notifications. Also would it be possible to use last known non-null data for example see the composed stream below.

```
Stream A : A, B, C, D....
Stream B : 1, null, 2, null....
Composed : (A,1),(B,1),(C,2),(D,2)....
```

I've just started playing with reactive streams idea, so please correct me if I've misunderstood the idea of reactive streams.

Comment: Dunno how it's in RxJS exactly, but in general the first problem is usually solved with `zip` after which the two streams are merged as a stream of pairs. Dunno again how the second problem should be solved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two operators that can serve for your propose.

**[Zip](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bnaya/2010/03/05/rx-for-beginners-part-7-zip-expression/)**: 

[image: Rx Zip]

Reference for RxJs: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md

**[CombineLatest](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bnaya/2010/03/10/rx-for-beginners-part-8-combine-latest-expression/)**:

[image: Rx CombineLatest]

Reference for RxJs: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md

The images explain the differences between both. Now you have merged the observable's you just need to filter, using [where](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/where.md), that will filter if one of the values is null.

Unfortunately neither operators can get this behavior that you describe:

```
Stream A : A, B, C, D, E....
Stream B : 1, null, 2, null, 3....
Composed : (A,1),(B,1),(C,2),(D,2)....
```

If you use Zip and Where (filtering null values after), the result will be:

```
Composed: (A,1),(C,2),(E,3)
```

If you use Where (filtering null values previously) and Zip, the result will be:

```
Composed: (A,1),(B,2),(C,3)
```

If you use CombineLatest will depend of the order that the events happens in the Streams, and of course, where you will put the `where` operator, the result can be different that what you shown, e.g.:

```
Stream A : A, B, C, D....
Stream B : 1, null, 2, null....
Composed : (A,1),(B,1),(C,1),(C,2),(D,2).... // OR
Composed : (A,1),(B,1),(B,2),(C,2),(D,2)....
```

Unless you have more specific requirements, I think one of the options that I mentioned is what you are looking for, feel free to add information.

There are several ways to compose observable's, other operators not mentioned are:

- [distinctUntilChanged](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md), could be added in the final of the composition, using the key selector function to limit for just part of zip or latest value.
- [switch](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmaplatest.md), used to combine one observable inside another.